# Error in qnorm: argument "p" is missing, with no default

Tags: r, normal-distribution, quantile

I'm trying to use R to calculate using a "perfect" normal distribution. In other words, I don't want to specify it from some sample points - I have none - I just want to feed it the mean and standard deviation and compute quantiles.

It seems I should use `qnorm` and I would assume to call it like `qnorm(mean=1000, sd=50`, but it complains `argument "p" is missing, with no default`. `p` looks to be the sample data but that really should be irrelevant if I know the mean and sd. If I omit the parameters entirely it actually works fine, but if I enter these two parameters it seems to expect `p`. What gives?

Here is a minimal, complete, verifiable example:

```
> qnorm(mean=1000, sd=50)
Error in qnorm(mean = 1000, sd = 50) : 
  argument "p" is missing, with no default
```

Here is my concise problem statement:

"When using the `qnorm` function what must I supply for the variable `p`?"

Here is the desired behavior:

```
qnorm(mean=1000, sd=50)(.095)
> the answer!!!!!!
```

Comment: `p` is a vector of probabilities.

Answer (score 0):

I understand - p is the actual input. `qnorm` always expects to return the number that is the answer; for some reason I expected a function that represented a normal distribution that you would then compute. e.g.

```
> qnorm(mean=1000, sd=75, p=0.9)
[1] 1096.116
```

Comment: Please add these in comments or merge it to your main question.

Comment: @Pascal add the answer to my main question?

Comment: By reading the help file, you get the answer. Anyway, it's closed.